# Openldap backup restore

Tags: backup, ldap, restore, openldap

I am trying to setup backup and restore and make sure it works.

Please note that database size on `ldap.old` is lot more then the `ldap`. The `/var/lib/ldap.old` is my existing database. I have renamed `/var/lib/ldap` for backup/restore testing.

I am getting the following error when restoring. Because of this I am not sure I have successfully restored everything.

```
...
added: "uid=user11123,ou=Abcd,ou=Industry Professional,dc=testdomain,dc=org" (0001cc9f)
added: "uid=user13123,ou=Abcd,ou=Industry Professional,dc=testdomain,dc=org" (0001cca0)
Error, entries missing!
  entry 79870: ou=industryprofessional,dc=testdomain,dc=org
  entry 79871: ou=abcd professional,ou=industryprofessional,dc=testdomain,dc=org
```

#### Disk usage:

```
[root@openldap]# du -khs ldap ldap.old/
3.3G    ldap
4.0G    ldap.old/
```

Here is my backup / restore process:

#### Backup:

```
slapcat -v -l backup_openldap.ldif
```

#### Restore:

```
/etc/init.d/ldap stop
mv /var/lib/ldap /var/lib/ldap.old
mkdir /var/lib/ldap
chmod go-rwx /var/lib/ldap
cp –rfp /var/lib/ldap.old/DB_CONFIG /var/lib/ldap

slapadd –v –l backup_openldap.ldif

chown ldap:ldap /var/lib/ldap
/etc/init.d/ldap start
```

How do I validate that I have restore all records successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should be aware of slapcat's [limitations](http://linux.die.net/man/8/slapcat):

```
For some backend types, your slapd(8) should not be running 
(at least, not in read-write mode) when you do this to ensure 
consistency of the database. It is always safe to run slapcat 
with the slapd-bdb(5), slapd-hdb(5), and slapd-null(5) backends.
```

So you better pack that **backup** in `/etc/init.d/ldap stop` and `/etc/init.d/ldap start` as well.

Before restarting `ldap` in the restore procedure, you can dump the just loaded data to a temporary file and compare that to the LDIF file you just used as input. I am pretty sure the LDIF output for `slapcat` is sorted by Distinguished Names so a `diff` should exit with exit-code 0.

```
...
chown ldap:ldap *

slapcat -l /var/tmp/test.ldif
diff /var/tmp/test.ldif /backup/openldap/backup_ldap2.diff
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
     echo 'differences found'
fi

/etc/init.d/ldap start
```

This of course assumes that `slapcat` is working correctly. If you do not trust that you should extract all data relevant to **you**, from the running DB with `ldap_search_ext()`, generate some output (dump or checksum) from that, and compare that with running the same code on the restored database (after starting `ldap` of course). That way you would notice if some data relevant to your usage is left out of the dump by `slapcat` (unlikely, but possible if it has a bug)